# TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined

Tags: angular, npm, typeerror, npm-install

I am using `Angular` first time when I use `ng serve` command,  it shows me this error -

```
C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:157
            if (pkg.main) {
                   ^
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined at

```
 C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:157:24
 at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:446:3)
```

Please suggest how to solve this-

Version detail of component is-

Node **6.10.2**

Cli **1.0.1**

npm **3.10.10**

Comment: It tell to you that your object `pkg` doesn't exist or is null at this part of code. Check your code and where your object is instanciate to solve this.

Comment: I didn't code yet, I just created an application by `ng new my-first-project` and navigated to its directory after this, when I am trying `ng serve` to build its source code then, it showing me this error.

Comment: I had the same thing happen to me. Apparently, my file system had become corrupted which completely explains the error because various files had become unreadable.